# MYSQL "SELECT *:not(id) FROM...". Is there something similar?

Tags: mysql, join

When I JOINing to tables which both have 'id' column, I getting the result with 'id' not from the table I need. And both these table has a lot of columns so I don't want to type them all in my query. Is it posible to do something similar to css :not like `SELECT table1.*, table2.*:not(id) FROM ...`? Or maybe there is some other solution?

Thanks

Comment: No, but I really wish there was.

Comment: Many people probably long for this, but almost everyone will tell you that it is better practice to always list out all the columns you wish to return so you do not have to change every select/function/procedure if you make a schema update.

Comment: Good grief, how lazy are you? ;-)

Comment: @Strawberry, ahah :). yeah, that's true!

Answer (score 4):

If you do **not** want a particular column from a table, then you cannot use the `*`, you have to type out all of the columns that you want to get.

Comment: Which one should probably do anyway, to ensure that a new column added to the table or view (or a reordering of existing columns) doesn't break the application.

Answer (score -1):

That select will be returning both `id` columns; it's your programming language's libraries that are presumably only giving you access to one.

That said, does

```
SELECT table2.*, table1.* ...
```

get you all the columns you need?

Answer (score -2):

I found a solution myself. Very simple. I just replaced my second table to the first place and first table now goes after JOIN. Seems mysql returns only the ID of the latest table.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: No. That's your application level code that's doing that